# How can i get multidimensional array to single variable?

Tags: php

The problem i cloud not get array value and assign to some variable. I want to send a msg to more then one numbers, the numbers from `DB`.This is the my array to hold the all mob numbers. Now the problem is i want to send msg all numbers from this array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mobile] => 9944176261
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mobile] => 9994444783
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mobile] => 9944176261
        )

)
,Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mob_no] => 9944176262
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mob_no] => 9944176263
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mob_no] => 9944176265
        )

)
```

Here is my msg sending code using SMS gateway.I want to assign the All the numbers to `receipientno` variable. based on this `receipientno` values to send the msg.

```
//msg code for customers
        $ch = curl_init();
        $user="username:pwd";
        $receipientno=$_POST['check_list'];
        $receipientno = implode(',', $receipientno);        
        $senderID="TEST SMS"; 
        $msgtxt=$_POST['message'];
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&msgtxt=$msgtxt");
        $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
        if(empty ($buffer))
        { echo " buffer is empty "; }
        else
        { echo $buffer; } 
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: so you want to get all the mobile number out of the array and put them into a common separated string?

Comment: foreach($array as $row ) {    $receipientno.= explode(',',array_column('mobile',$array));  }

Comment: you are right @MarkTwigg

Comment: @JYoThI  does not working `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` error

Comment: try my posted answers @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan

Comment: yes i will try bro

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your POST array structured this way:

```
$arr = array(
array(
    0 => array
        (
            'mobile' => 9944176261
        ),
    1 => array
        (
            'mobile' => 9994444783
        ),
    2 => array
        (
            'mobile' => 9944176261
        )

),
array
(
0 => array
    (
        'mob_no' => 9944176262
    ),
1 => array
    (
        'mob_no' => 9944176263
    ),

2 => array
    (
        'mob_no' => 9944176265
    )
)
)
;
```

You can get a comma separated list of all the `mob_no` and `mobile` indexes with this snippet.

```
$receipientsNo = "";
foreach($arr as $row){
$recipientsNo .= ",". implode(',', array_map(function ($input) {
  if(isset($input['mobile']))
    return $input['mobile'];
  elseif (isset($input['mob_no']))
     return $input['mob_no'];
}, $row));
}

$recipientsNo = ltrim($recipientsNo,",");
```

**UPDATE:**
You'll need to update your `//msg code for customers` code like so:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$user="username:pwd";

$receipientsNo = "";
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $row){
    $receipientsNo .= ",". implode(',', array_map(function ($input) {
      if(isset($input['mobile']))
        return $input['mobile'];
      elseif (isset($input['mob_no']))
         return $input['mob_no'];
    }, $row));
}

$receipientsNo = ltrim($receipientsNo,",");

$senderID="TEST SMS"; 
$msgtxt=$_POST['message'];
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientsNo&msgtxt=$msgtxt");
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
if(empty ($buffer))
{ echo " buffer is empty "; }
else
{ echo $buffer; } 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: but why should i change the structure of the array?

Comment: I don't suggest you change your array structure. My example uses the same array as you provided in your question.

Comment: this is the problem `I want to get all the mobile number out of the array and put them into a common separated variable`

Comment: what error does it show? Because I just tested it and it worked.

Comment: `Notice: Array to string conversion ` line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&msgtxt=$msgtxt");`

Comment: because `$receipientno` value is array format . this is the problem  `Array ( [0] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9944176261 ) [1] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9994444783 ) [2] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9486131290 ) )`. i know i tring to array to string. but how to fix

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan see my update on the answer. The `$receipientno` variable will be a string not an array, if you implement it the way I suggested.

Comment: yes i tried your solution i get lot of warnings 'Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array' and `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed ` and `Notice: Undefined variable: recipientsno`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        <?php

    $receipientno='';

    $ss = array(
    array(
        0 => array
            (
                'mobile' => 9944176261
            ),
        1 => array
            (
                'mobile' => 9994444783
            ),
        2 => array
            (
                'mobile' => 9944176261
            )

    ),
    array
    (
    0 => array
        (
            'mob_no' => 9944176262
        ),
    1 => array
        (
            'mob_no' => 9944176263
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'mob_no' => 9944176265
        )
    )
    )
    ;


    foreach($ss as $row ) {

        if(isset($row[0]['mobile']))
        {
             $receipientno.= implode(',',array_column($row,'mobile')); 


        }
        else if(isset($row[0]['mob_no']))
        {
             $receipientno.= implode(',',array_column($row,'mob_no')); 
        }

    }

    echo $receipientno;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
        foreach($ss as $row ) {


        foreach($row as $new ){


        if(isset($new['mobile']))
        $receipientno.=$new['mobile'].",";

        else if(isset($new['mob_no']))
            $receipientno.=$new['mob_no'].",";


        }

    }

    echo rtrim($receipientno,",");
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
9944176261,9994444783,99441762619944176262,9944176263,9944176265
```

Comment: i think your doing mistake somewhere i tested code its working @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan

Comment: can you copy my source and test here http://phpfiddle.org/ @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan

Comment: i just copied and run but the `array_column` function in black color

Comment: oh okay what is your php version ?

Comment: yes i test your code working in fiddle but in my environment does not working. my verson 5.1.16

Comment: yeah its need above 5.5 something i'm not sure .okay i will try in another method

Comment: sry bro does not wrk

Comment: yes i change your code like this `foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $row ) ` and i get this error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` when i print the `receipientno` i get result same array format `Array ( [0] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9944176261 ) [1] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9994444783 ) [2] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9486131290 ) )`

Comment: may be $_POST['check_list'] empty @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan

Comment: i checked it have values like `Array ( [0] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9944176261 ) [1] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9994444783 ) [2] => Array ( [mob_no] => 9486131290 ) )`